# Java function question

Tags: java

Alright I am very new to Java and am trying to develop an application to teach myself how to use the language.

I have been copying and pasting the same few lines of code all over, and I know that there is a way to consolidate this into a function, but cannot quite figure it out.

```
 FileOutputStream fout4 = openFileOutput("building1hourly.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 OutputStreamWriter osw4 = new OutputStreamWriter(fout4);
 osw4.write("" +iHourlyAfter);
 osw4.flush();
 osw4.close();
```

Now isn't there some type of way I could do something like this

```
public void writerFunction("What to write to file", "name stream", "name writer", "MODE"){insert above code here}
```

Comment: yes, just put all these lines inside your function and replace the actual values with the argument names. what's the problem ?

Comment: You already answered it yourself.

Comment: A better way to teach yourself the Java language is to do the Oracle Java tutorial, or read a good Java textbook.  If you try to learn a language by leaping in and trying to develop something, you are liable to pick up a lot of misconceptions and bad habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes absolutely:

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName, String contents, int mode) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput(fileName, mode);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
    osw.write(contents);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just trying to make sure I have the concept down right.  So if I have that function all I would need to do is: writeToFile(String fileName, String contents, int mode);

Comment: actually `writeToFile("building1hourly.txt", "" + iHourlyAfter, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);` would do the trick if what you mean is to call function (actually in Javaland we call them methods)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great job so far. Learning programming is just like learning math (except more fun), you can read about it all you want in a book, but you don't really understand concepts until you DO them. You're going about this the right way.

Now, to answer your question: Yes, you can encapsulate the process of writing to a file in a function. Let's call it `writeToFile`. You want to "call" this function by sending it **arguments**. The arguments are the information that the function needs to do its work.

There are two sides to a function: the **declaration**, and the **invocation**. Just like in math, you can define a function `f(x)`, where `f` does something. For example: say I have the function `f(x) = 2x - 4`. That equation is what we call the function declaration, in that we are defining what `f` does, and you are defining the **parameters** that it accepts, namely a single value `x`. Then you want to apply that function on a certain value `x`, so you might do something like: `f(4)`. This is the function **invocation**. You are invoking, or **calling** the function, and sending `4` as the **argument**. The code that invokes a function is called the **caller**.

Let's start with the declaration of the function that you want to build:

`public void writeToFile (String data, String fileName)`

This function defines two parameters in its signature; it expects a `String` containing the `data` you will write to the file, and the `fileName` to which we will write the `data`. The `void` means that this function does not return any data back to the caller.

The complete function, the body of which you provided in your post:

```
public void writeToFile (String data, String fileName){
    FileOutputStream fout4 = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw4 = new OutputStreamWriter(fout4);
    osw4.write("" +iHourlyAfter);
    osw4.flush();
    osw4.close();
}
```

Now you will want to call, or invoke this function from somewhere else in your code. You can do this like so:

```
writeToFile("stuff I want to write to a file", "myFile.txt");
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and makes more sense when I think of it in "f(4)" terms.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If you like programming, then get good at it and keep practicing. It pays very well ;-)